# Create activity on click of ActionBar back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar

Right now I have an app that takes the user from the `SignupActivity` directly to the activity to `EditProfileActivity`.

It creates that one like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditProfileActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user", user);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The `EditProfileActivity` has a back button in the action bar that when clicked closes the app.
What I want to do is instead of closing the app to take the user to my `MainActivity`.

I'm using the `EditProfileActivity` at other point in my app to edit the profile but coming from the `MainActivity`. In that case the back button returns to the `MainActivity` which is exactly what I want.

How can I achive this?
Do I need to start the `MainActivity` from the `SignupActivity` and then take it to the `EditProfile` or can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two simple options, at least:
- If it's possible, launch your `MainActivity` with some extra, verify if that extra is present on its `onCreate` method and then start your `EditProfileActivity`.
- Use `startActivityForResult` to start your `EditProfileActivity` and start your `MainActivity` when needed on its `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: The second option, in which activity `onActivityResult` method should I start my `MainActivity`?

Comment: If you use `startActivityForResult` on `SignUpActivity`, you should override the `onActivityResult` method on `SignUpActivity` itself.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going for the second option

Answer (score 0):

In your `EditProfileActivity`, add below lines of code:

```
// Required to start MainActivity when ActionBar back icon pressed
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Required to start MainActivity when HW back KEY pressed
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Hope this will help~